# Using Dodge (Mythic) as an Immediate Action

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat

Dodge (Mythic)

> The bonus to AC from Dodge increases by 1. As an immediate action, you can expend one use of mythic power to grant yourself an additional +10 dodge bonus to AC against one attack.

How does this feat work when a fighter with this feat is using it against an attacker? Does the player need to declare that he will use the mythic power to grant additional +10 dodge bonus before the result of the attacking creature is revealed? Can he simply declare it after the DM reveals the result of the attack?

For example. A 9th level fighter has 27 AC. He is attacked by a giant that has +19 attack. The DM rolls the dice and he gets a 15. 15+19 adds up to 34. The fighter would be normally hit by the attack. Can he declare he will use his immediate action to use Dodge (Mythic) after the DM reveals he would normally hit the character?

Comment: The rules for immediate actions are, as far as I can tell, the same as in D&D 3.5.  Is your question significantly different than http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/35921/immediate-actions-during-other-actions?rq=1

Comment: While an answer on that question does answer this one, the questions themselves are pretty different.  There's also a lot of controversy around whether that answer's part that applies to this question is correct...

Comment: What I want to know is if declaring the use of an immediate action that gives you AC after the DM telling you the result of the attack is impossible or not.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question is unclear from a RAW standpoint.  There are essentially two camps: one who believe that attacks happen as a single atomic step and one who believe that attacks happen as a set of discrete micro-steps in a MTG-like fashion.  People who hold the first position would say the answer to your question is no, as declaring an attack, rolling an attack, resolving whether it hits or not, rolling damage, etc. all go onto the 'stack' as a single entity.  People who hold the second position would say that the fighter can take the immediate action at any time before the hit is confirmed.  This would usually mean either that he can take the action after an attack is rolled but before the GM reveals whether the roll is a hit or not (how does the fighter know that the ogre has +19?) or that he can take the action after the attack is declared but not rolled and should be given the opportunity to do so before the roll is made.  In no case could he invoke the AC boost after the GM specifically declared the attack a hit.

Short answer: No.

You can see a more in-depth discussion of both sides [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/35921/immediate-actions-during-other-actions?rq=1).  While the discussion regards the D&D 3.5 system, the interrupt action system and the resolution of attack rolls is the same in Pathfinder.

Comment: If you're interested, another Comment discussion about the timing issues associated with immediate actions occurs [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/49768/8610).

Comment: If the GM announces the result quickly not giving the player the chance to say a thing. Does it still counts?

Comment: @Azrael if the fighter is able to take the action in between rolling and the results announcement he ought to be given the opportunity to do so.  To clarify: No, but doing that is being a jerk GM and you shouldn't do it in the same way you shouldn't say WhatAreYouDoingThisRoundTooLateHaHa on each of your players' initiatives (but you *could*).  If being a jerk sounds fun to you, play Hackmaster, not Pathfinder.