# Does the Leshy Ancestry Feat Grasping Reach reduce Deadly/Fatal damage dice?

Tags: feats, weapons, pathfinder-2e, races

The Leshy ancestry feat [Grasping Reach](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1037) allows the Leshy to use most two handed weapons as [Reach](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=192) weapons, in exchange for reducing the weapons damage die by one step.

Does this reduction apply to the [Deadly](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=174) and [Fatal](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=178) properties though? Does a [Greatpick](https://2e.aonprd.com/Weapons.aspx?ID=23) for example, become a 1d8 Fatal D12 weapon, or a 1d8 Fatal D10 weapon?

Answer (score 4):

### Deadly, no

Even though [Deadly](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=174) references adding 'weapon dice', is specifically exempt from changing its die size.

> An ability that changes the size of the weapon's normal damage dice doesn't change the size of its deadly die.

### Fatal, probably

[Fatal](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=178) is less clear, but I believe it *would* be affected by the Leshy ability, and other things that affect die size.

> The fatal trait includes a die size. On a critical hit, the weapon’s damage die increases to that die size instead of the normal die size, and the weapon adds one additional damage die of the listed size.

It is changing the die used by the weapon, and does not preempt changing it like Deadly does. Arguably, this counts as an [increase to die size](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=226) and it could not be increased further, but the rules do not prevent you from both increasing and decreasing die size.

Where this gets really muddy is that [Pathfinder 2e does not define the order of simultaneous effects](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/196891/28326). Are you allowed to decrease your die size *then* increase it to the Fatal amount? Or do both effects have to be carried out to the best of their ability? As a GM, I would have you used the Fatal die minus one step.